# Extracting Thumbnail URL from Video URL

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

So, I have a video URL in an Amazon S3 bucket. I must extract the thumbnail image (preview image) from the video URL. The catch is that I do not have the luxury to download or upload the complete video since it takes time. My approach is something like this.
I first created a blob object containing the first few seconds of that video using something like this.

```
  const chunkSize = 1024*1024; // 1MB
  const start = 0;
  const end = chunkSize - 1;
  const rangeHeader = `bytes=${start}-${end}`;
  
  const VideoResponse = await axios.get(url, { 
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: { Range: rangeHeader }
  });

  const chunkData = VideoResponse.data; 
  
  const videoBlob = new Blob([chunkData], { type: 'video/mp4' });
  const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
  console.log({chunkData, videoBlob, videoUrl});
```

Console gives me something like this

```
{
  chunkData: <Buffer 00 00 00 1c 66 74 79 70 6d 70 34 32 00 00 00 00 69 73 6f 6d 61 76 63 31 6d 70 34 32 00 02 bd ab 6d 6f 6f 76 00 00 00 6c 6d 76 68 64 00 00 00 00 c7 6f ... 1048526 more bytes>,
  videoBlob: Blob { size: 1048576, type: 'video/mp4' },
  videoUrl: 'blob:nodedata:764fce87-792f-47e8-bc3e-15921ee5787f'
}
```

Now, there are many options after this. I am trying to download this blob object by converting it into a file. After I successfully convert it into an mp4 file, I can easily take a screenshot of it using `fluent-ffmpeg` package. However, I couldn't convert it into a file. If I try to do something like this

```
  const BlobResponse = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: videoUrl,
    responseType: 'stream'
  });

  const file = fs.createWriteStream(`video.mp4`);
  BlobResponse.data.pipe(file);
  
  file.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log(`There was an error writing the file. Details: $ {error}`);
  });

  file.on('finish', () => {
    file.close();
    console.log("File downloaded successfully");
  });
```

But it throws me the error `AxiosError: Unsupported protocol blob:`

I also tried to directly convert the blob object to a jpeg object but to no avail.

I have searched **complete StackOverflow**, and I have not found a single solution working so please let me know why those are not working or if there is any new solution to do this.

Comment: You have raw video data as I see, could you use it as input for ffmpeg, with `createReadStream` for example?